# Changing text colour outside a plygon shape

Tags: css

```
<style>
  .heading-container {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 24.75%, 49.5% 49.88%, 99% 75%, 0% 75%);
    background: #000;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  h1 {
    color: white;
  }
</style>
<div style="background-color:pink">
  <div class="heading-container">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum Heading Test Lorem Ipsum Heading Test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

How could I go about achieving a result where the full sentence is visible however the text which is currently white that is being cut off is black on the pink background.

[image]

So its something like the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that there are better ways (see @TemaniAfif's answer), but a simple solution is to use two layers of text:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.heading-container {
  padding: 20px;
}

.clipped {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 24.75%, 49.5% 49.88%, 99% 75%, 0% 75%);
}
```

Do note that this doesn't work very well when you try to select the text.

Try it:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
}

.heading-container {
  padding: 20px;
}

.clipped {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 24.75%, 49.5% 49.88%, 99% 75%, 0% 75%);
  background: #000;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
}

.clipped h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="heading-container">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum Heading Test Lorem Ipsum Heading Test</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="heading-container clipped">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum Heading Test Lorem Ipsum Heading Test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a background combined with mix-blend-mode and filter

```css
.heading-container {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #0000 50%, #fff 50.1%); /* transparent and white in the gradient */
  padding: 20px;
  isolation: isolate; /* don't blend with bottom layer*/
  filter: invert(1); /* invert the coloration (white -> black and black -> white) */
}

h1 {
  color: white; /* also white here */
  mix-blend-mode: difference; /* difference between white and white will give black so the text will be half white and half black */
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:pink">
  <div class="heading-container">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum Heading Test Lorem Ipsum Heading Test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```